# Why isn't geocoder = new google.maps.geocoder(); working in my app?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to reverse geocode an address for an app so that the address shows up in a window at the bottom of the page and in a second window, you see your coordinates, accuracy, speed, and what time the information was updated. When I run my code without the reverse geocoding part, everything runs fine, but when I try to reverse geocode, I not only get nothing in the first window, but the window with coordinates, accuracy, and speed is blank as well. I don't understand why the second window is being affected by my reverse geocoding code and I'm not sure why an address isn't showing up in the first window.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
  //$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('mobileinit');
  $.mobile.page.prototype.options.defaultPageTransition = "none";
  $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.theme = "a";
  $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.theme = "a";
  $.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.addBacBtn = "true";


});
var geocoder;
var currentLocation;

function init() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    //Use the Geolocation API to get current location and track it as you move
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showLocation, locationError);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation not supported on this device");
    return;
  }
  // Define "click" events for "queryPlaces()" function
  $("#policeItem").on("click", function() {
    queryPlaces('Police');
  });
  $("#fsItem").on("click", function() {
    queryPlaces('Fire Station');
  });
  $("#tdItem").on("click", function() {
    queryPlaces('Transportation Department');
  });
  $("#ahItem").on("click", function() {
    queryPlaces('Animal Hospital');
  });
  $("#hospitalItem").on("click", function() {
    queryPlaces('Hospital');
  });



} //end  of init function     

function showLocation(location) {
  //var temp = "Geocoding Not In Operation... Sorry";
  //$('#loc').html(temp);
  geocoder = new google.maps.geocoder();
  currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);

  geocoder.geocode({
    'location': curentLocation
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        $('#loc').html(results[0].formatted_address);
      } else {
        $('#loc').html('No address found');
      }
    } else {
      $('#loc').html('Unavailable to determine address');
    }
  }); //end of geocode method



  var info = "Coordinates: " + parseFloat(location.coords.latitude).toFixed(3) + ", ";
  info += parseFloat(location.coords.longitude).toFixed(3) + "<br/>";
  info += "Accuracy: " + parseFloat(location.coords.accuracy) + " meters" + "<br/>";
  info += "Speed: " + parseFloat(location.coords.speed) + " m/s" + "<br/>";
  info += "Updated: " + new Date(location.timestamp).toLocaleString();
  $('#acc').html(info);
} //end of showLocation function        

function locationError(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      alert("Geolocation access denied or disabled. To enable geolocation " + "on your iPhone, go to Settings > General > Location Services");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Current location not available");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("Timeout");
      break;
    default:
      alert("unknown error");
      break;
  }
}

function updateDist(value) {

  $("#distVal").html("" + value + " meters");
}

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#homeView", init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>


<!-- Home Page Begins-->
<div id="homeView" data-role="page" data-title="Wildlife Vehicle Collisions" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="header1">
    <h1>WVC</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <img src="images/wildlife-3.jpg" alt="WVC Management" />
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="b" class="ui-content">
      <a href="#findView" class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left">Find Nearby</a>
      <a href="#report" class="ui-btn ui-icon-eye ui-btn-icon-left">Report Collisions</a>
      <a href="#videos" class="ui-btn ui-icon-video ui-btn-icon-left">Videos</a>
      <a href="#photos" class="ui-btn ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-left">Photos</a>
    </div>
    <!-- links -->
  </div>
  <!-- content -->
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Copyright by resop</p>
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- page -->

<!-- findView Page Begins-->
<div id="findView" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="header1">
    <a href="#homeView" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Home</a>
    <h1>What's Nearby</h1>
    <a href="#settingsView" class="ui-btn ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Settings</a>
  </div>
  <!--header End-->

  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li id="policeItem"><a href="#resultsView">Police Departments</a></li>
      <li id="fsItem"><a href="#resultsView">Fire Stations</a></li>
      <li id="tdItem"><a href="#resultsView">Transportation Departments</a></li>
      <li id="ahItem"><a href="#resultsView">Animal Hospitals</a></li>
      <li id="hospitalItem"><a href="#resultsView">Hospitals</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Current Location</h2>
    <div id="loc"></div>
    <div id="acc"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Content End -->

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer1">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#homeView" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-top">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#findView" class="ui-btn ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-top">Find</a></li>
        <li><a href="#report" class="ui-btn ui-icon-eye ui-btn-icon-top">Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#videos" class="ui-btn ui-icon-video ui-btn-icon-top">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#photos" class="ui-btn ui-icon-grid ui-btn-icon-top">Photos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--navbar end-->
  </div>
  <!--footer end-->
</div>
<!--findView Page End-->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the debugger logging?

Comment: All I'm getting is this: ###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv

Comment: In the code above I'm getting these errors: Home
Find
Report
Videos
Photos
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Comment: That is because you have to supply the api key with the url. Do you have that? It is not in the above snippet for security reasons.

Comment: I tried adding an api key to my code and nothing changed... Is there a specific place I need to put it in my code? Maybe it was too high or low

Comment: can you post some test data you are receiving? It is hard to test your snippet without any data.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I did need an API key and part of the google maps API Geocode code had been decommissioned. The following code worked:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=places"></script>
        <style>
            #mapDiv { height: 100vh; }
            header { position: absolute; background-color: black; color: white; z-index: 1; right: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <div id="mapDiv"></div>
        <script>
        var apikey = "AIzaSyDV4cbTEeLmiXaPMIrEwAKB8xFGxvdDS1s",
            map;

        //runtime
        $(document).ready(init);

        function init(){
            //assign event listeners

            //start the app
            getLocation();
        }

        function initMap(lat, lng){
            //create Google map
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector("#mapDiv"), {
                center: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 14
            });
        }

        function getLocation(){
            //can we get lat/lng from this device?
            if (!navigator || !navigator.geolocation){
                //handle error: lat/lng not available
                return;
            }
            //get lat/lng from device
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
                var lat = pos.coords.latitude,
                    lng = pos.coords.longitude,
                    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat + "," + lng +"&key=" + apikey;

                //open Google map centered on device
                initMap(lat, lng);

                //get location data from Google
                $.ajax({url: url})
                      .done(function(data){
                          document.querySelector("header").textContent = data.results[0].formatted_address;
                      });
            });
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```